# No Bluetooth adapter is present

Tags: bluetooth, vaio

I've a Sony Vaio VPCEH1S0E and I've got a problem with Bluetooth.

My Bluetooth applet is running but there's no way to configure my Bluetooth device because Ubuntu says that "no adapter is present".

This is the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

This is the output of `hcitool dev`:

```
Devices:
```

---

This is the output of `dmesg | tail` after I've turned on Bluetooth:

```
[ 1590.367523] hci_cmd_timer: hci0 command tx timeout
[ 1591.367014] hci_cmd_timer: hci0 command tx timeout
[ 1592.366483] hci_cmd_timer: hci0 command tx timeout
[ 1593.365992] hci_cmd_timer: hci0 command tx timeout
```

---

And finally this is the output of `lsmod`:

```
bluetooth             166112  13 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
```

So what can I do to find my Bluetooth adapter?

Answer (score 2):

I am also using VPCEH Sony VAIO and I got both bluetooth and Wifi working simultaneously. This is how i did it.

Run `lsmod | grep sony` and you will find a module `sony_laptop`.

Blacklist it by editing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and inserting `blacklist sony_laptop`.

Save the file and reboot.

Now you should be able to access both Bluetooth and Wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've faced already [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/898826).

Run `hciconfig` in the console, this will give you output similar to this one:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:66 acl:0 sco:0 commands:21 errors:1
```

If your BT adapter MAC address is 00:00:00:00:00:00, then all you can do is wait until someone will provide a fix in mainline. Sorry :)

Comment: I have a MAC Address, yet I still can't.... hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

Comment: @palhmbs: Then your issue might be something else. Have a look into kernel log first.